# "Изменить" and "измениться"

Tags: грамматика

I didn't get how to conjugate the verb change for make that phrases.

What change? - Can I say "что изменить"?
What is changing? - Can I say "что меняется"? 
Nothing changes - Can I say "ничего не меняется"?
Nothing will change - Can I say "ничего не изменится"?

Do "изменить" and "изменится" in their infinitive form have the same meaning?

Comment: I'm sorry, It's not really clear. Can you check the example that i post? I know i can check the verbs but my question is about how this verb interact with other elements in the phrase like here: What change? - Can I say "что изменить"? What is changing? - Can I say "что меняется"? Nothing changes - Can I say "ничего не меняется"? Nothing will change - Can I say "ничего не изменится"? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What change? - Can I say "что изменить"?

if you meant `What to change?` it is correct. However, I'd rather say `Что поменять?`

> What is changing? - Can I say "что меняется"?

correct. Can also be `Что изменяется?`

> Nothing changes - Can I say "ничего не меняется"?

correct. Can also be `Ничего не изменяется`

> Nothing will change - Can I say "ничего не изменится"?

correct. Can also be `Ничего не поменяется`

> Do "изменить" and "изменится" in their infinitive form have the same meaning?

No. `изменить` means 'to change something', `изменитЬся` means 'to self-change' and your word `изменится` is not an infinitive but a second singular form of the verb `изменитЬся` something like 'he will change (himself)'

Comment: thanks so much for clarify what I ask :)

Answer (score 6):

"Изменить" is when one changes something, while "измениться" is when something is changed, compare the following two phrases:

> Я изменил распорядок дня.

and

> Когда ко мне переехал сын, мой распорядок дня изменился.

You guessed all the verb forms correctly. For future references you can use the Russian part of Wiktionary, quite often verbs are given there with conjugation, and ["изменить"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) is no exception to this.